# Why do I get wrong sum from group when using subreport's return value?

Tags: variables, jasper-reports, subreport

I have JasperReport's **sub_employment** with a SubReport **sub_salary**
I'd like to sum the return values from the SubReport.

This works, but the sum ignore the last record.

See the result PDF

[image]

I'd tried every possibility from "evaluation time" and "reset type"

**Variable**

```
<variable name="ACTUAL_HOURS" class="java.lang.Double" resetType="Column" calculation="Sum">
    <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[new Double(0.0)]]></initialValueExpression>
</variable>
<variable name="ACTUAL_SALARY" class="java.lang.Double" resetType="Column" calculation="Sum">
    <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[new Double(0.0)]]></initialValueExpression>
</variable>
<variable name="ACTUAL_SALARY_MONTH" class="java.lang.Double" resetType="Column" calculation="Sum">
    <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[new Double(0.0)]]></initialValueExpression>
</variable>
<variable name="SUM_ACTUAL_HOURS" class="java.lang.Double" calculation="Sum">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{ACTUAL_HOURS}]]></variableExpression>
    <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[new Double(0.0)]]></initialValueExpression>
</variable>
<variable name="SUM_ACTUAL_SALARY" class="java.lang.Double" calculation="Sum">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{ACTUAL_SALARY}]]></variableExpression>
    <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[new Double(0.0)]]></initialValueExpression>
</variable>
<variable name="SUM_ACTUAL_SALARY_MONTH" class="java.lang.Double" calculation="Sum">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{ACTUAL_SALARY_MONTH}]]></variableExpression>
    <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[new Double(0.0)]]></initialValueExpression>
</variable>
<variable name="ENTRY_DATE" class="java.util.Date" calculation="Lowest">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{entry_date}]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
<variable name="BUSINESS_FUNCTION" class="java.lang.String">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{business_function}]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

**Band**:

```
<band height="14">
        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{IS_VALID}]]></printWhenExpression>
        <subreport>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="489" height="14" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="0b445260-50f1-4a00-bd12-b278d3d18ec1"/>
            <subreportParameter name="REPORT_RESOURCE_BUNDLE">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_RESOURCE_BUNDLE}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <subreportParameter name="OWNER">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{OWNER}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <subreportParameter name="PRODUCT_NAME">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{PRODUCT_NAME}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <subreportParameter name="COPYRIGHT">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{COPYRIGHT}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <subreportParameter name="USER">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{USER}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <subreportParameter name="USER_FIRSTNAME">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{USER_FIRSTNAME}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <subreportParameter name="USER_LASTNAME">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{USER_LASTNAME}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <subreportParameter name="USER_EMAIL">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{USER_EMAIL}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <subreportParameter name="USER_NAME">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{USER_NAME}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <subreportParameter name="EMPLOYEE_ABBREVIATION">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{EMPLOYEE_ABBREVIATION}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <subreportParameter name="REPORT_NAME">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_NAME}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <subreportParameter name="PRINT_DATE">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{PRINT_DATE}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <subreportParameter name="VALID_DATE">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{VALID_DATE}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <subreportParameter name="SHOW_EMPLOYMENT_TOTAL">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{SHOW_EMPLOYMENT_TOTAL}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <subreportParameter name="ROUND_SALARY_MONTH_SINGLE">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{ROUND_SALARY_MONTH_SINGLE}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <subreportParameter name="ROUND_SALARY_YEAR_TOTAL">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{ROUND_SALARY_YEAR_TOTAL}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <subreportParameter name="ROUND_SALARY_YEAR_SINGLE">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{ROUND_SALARY_YEAR_SINGLE}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <subreportParameter name="ROUND_SALARY_MONTH_TOTAL">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{ROUND_SALARY_MONTH_TOTAL}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$F{hr_employment\$hr_employee_salary}]]></dataSourceExpression>
            <returnValue subreportVariable="SUM_ACTUAL_SALARY_MONTH" toVariable="ACTUAL_SALARY_MONTH"/>
            <returnValue subreportVariable="SUM_ACTUAL_SALARY" toVariable="ACTUAL_SALARY"/>
            <returnValue subreportVariable="SUM_ACTUAL_HOURS" toVariable="ACTUAL_HOURS"/>
            <subreportExpression><![CDATA["sub_salary.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
    </band>
```

**Summary**

```
<summary>
    <band height="15">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="0" y="1" width="150" height="14" uuid="79b0b8d3-e91d-4b24-81fe-b40c16934fd8"/>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="10"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Total"]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="#,##0.00" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement style="label-W-B-L" x="360" y="1" width="70" height="14" uuid="747fd18d-4afe-4343-bd66-ee8897309e59"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="10"/>
                <paragraph leftIndent="2"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{SUM_ACTUAL_SALARY_MONTH}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="#,##0.00" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement style="label-W-B-L" x="255" y="1" width="35" height="14" uuid="01a90af5-5fec-42e5-a69e-be21f034b51b"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="10"/>
                <paragraph leftIndent="2"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{SUM_ACTUAL_HOURS}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="#,##0.00" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement style="label-W-B-L" x="290" y="1" width="70" height="14" uuid="7dfc669e-3d34-4aa0-afc0-b9be20db5a7a"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="10"/>
                <paragraph leftIndent="2"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{SUM_ACTUAL_SALARY}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <line>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="489" height="1" uuid="f7997151-3c20-4e44-b574-c07709f3b35f"/>
            <graphicElement>
                <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
            </graphicElement>
        </line>
    </band>
</summary>
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39338449/how-to-sum-the-values-returned-by-a-subreport-placed-in-detail-band
The usual solution in such cases is to specify a calculation (like sum) for the subreport return value.  The master report variable would generally need to have calculation="System" so that the regular variable calculation mechanism does not interfere with the returned values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this way the **calculation** of the variable

```
<variable name="SUM_ACTUAL_SALARY_MONTH" class="java.lang.Double" calculation="Sum">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{ACTUAL_SALARY_MONTH}]]></variableExpression>
    <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[new Double(0.0)]]></initialValueExpression>
</variable>
```

is done **before** the `$V{ACTUAL_SALARY_MONTH}` is returned from the sub-report.

You have **multiple solutions**:

## Add last value in your `textField`

```
    $V{SUM_ACTUAL_SALARY_MONTH}.doubleValue()+$V{ACTUAL_SALARY_MONTH}.doubleValue()
```

The textField expression would be:

```
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="#,##0.00" isBlankWhenNull="true">
        <reportElement style="label-W-B-L" x="255" y="1" width="35" height="14" uuid="01a90af5-5fec-42e5-a69e-be21f034b51b"/>
        <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
            <font size="10"/>
            <paragraph leftIndent="2"/>
        </textElement>
        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{SUM_ACTUAL_SALARY_MONTH}.doubleValue()+$V{ACTUAL_SALARY_MONTH}.doubleValue()]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

**NOTE:** The variable `ACTUAL_SALARY_MONTH` return value from subreport should not have calculation and resetType.

```
<variable name="ACTUAL_SALARY_MONTH" class="java.lang.Double">
    <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[new Double(0.0)]]></initialValueExpression>
</variable>
```

## Use the sum function on the return value.

The main variable needs to have calculation `System`

> no calculation is done and the expression is not evaluated, the value
>   of this variable will be the last value set on it. Useful to store
>   partial results or the final result of a computation.

**Main variable**

```
<variable name="SUM_ACTUAL_SALARY_MONTH" class="java.lang.Double" calculation="System"/>
```

**Sub report return value**

```
<returnValue subreportVariable="SUM_ACTUAL_SALARY" toVariable="SUM_ACTUAL_SALARY_MONTH" calculation="Sum"/>
```

Note: How `calculation="Sum"` is used on `returnValue`.

Comment: This works if i have more than 1 group. But in case i have only 1 group, i get a empty total line.
[https://snag.gy/f8ykDG.jpg](https://snag.gy/f8ykDG.jpg)

Comment: @Alex I can't reproduce this, also with only 1 record I get the correct total, SUM_ACTUAL_SALARY_MONTH=0, ACTUAL_SALARY_MONTH=last return value, (I'm considering that the textField is in summary band (hence evaluationTime after subreport), otherwise on textField you should set evaluationTime=report

Comment: I’ve tried all different `evaluationTimes`. Also i tried 
`IF($V{SUM_ACTUAL_HOURS}==null,$V{SUM_ACTUAL_HOURS},$V{SUM_ACTUAL_HOURS}.doubleValue()+$V{ACTUAL_HOURS}.doubleValue())`
But it prints null. I don’t understand how it can be **null** if I set the `Initial Value Expression` to `new Double(0.0) `

Comment: @Alex, I have test with a similar test report and I do not have this problem, where is your textField in the summary band?

Comment: Yes, in the summary band. But i have the same problem if i put it in the `Page Footer`

Comment: @Alex Ok summary band (just like to confirm that we had same setup), have you tried to visualize the 2 variables in 2 different textFields (to see what value they have?)?

Comment: @Alex I add some info in post, on the variable that you return from subreport no need to set calculation and resetType

Comment: i found an solution with `$V{SUM_ACTUAL_HOURS}==null?
 $V{ACTUAL_HOURS}:
 $V{SUM_ACTUAL_HOURS}.doubleValue()+$V{ACTUAL_HOURS}.doubleValue()` but it works only with my old setup.

Comment: @Alex I also added to post how you can use calculation on return value