# How to sum the values returned by a subreport placed in detail band?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a report and a subreport that basically prints this:
[image]

Here is the code for the main report:

```
<jasperReport>
    <queryString><![CDATA[
select 1 as "RECORD", 'A' as "GROUP"
from dual
  union all
select 2, 'A'
from dual
  union all
select 3, 'B'
from dual
  union all
select 4, 'B'
from dual]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="RECORD" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="GROUP" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <variable name="return" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <group name="group">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{GROUP}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupFooter>
            <band height="20">
                <staticText>
                    <text><![CDATA[End of group ]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{GROUP}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <staticText>
                    <text><![CDATA[The sum of returned values for the group]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </band>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
    <detail>
        <band height="20">
            <staticText>
                <text><![CDATA[Record]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{RECORD}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <subreport>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <returnValue subreportVariable="return" toVariable="return"/>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["subreport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <staticText>
                <text><![CDATA[Subreport returned]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField evaluationTime="Band">
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{return}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

and the code for the subreport:

```
<jasperReport>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select * from dual]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="DUMMY" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <variable name="return" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[new BigDecimal(Math.random())]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
</jasperReport>
```

What I want is to print the sum of the returned values for the group in the group band (header or footer).

I know it's not possible to accumulate the value in a variable because the evaluation of the variables always occurs before the subreport can return it's result. So I would be summing a bunch of nulls.

I've seen people saying to make the sum inside a text field placed in a band after the subreport, but never managed to make it work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify a calculation type (like sum) when returning values from subreports.  Therefore if you want to sum returned values for each group, you'll have to do something like this:

```
<variable name="returnSum" class="java.math.BigDecimal" calculation="System" resetType="Group" resetGroup="group"/>
...
<returnValue subreportVariable="return" toVariable="returnSum" calculation="Sum"/>
```

Comment: It worked fine for "Sum", "Count" and "Highest". For "First", "Lowest" and "Standard deviation" I got 0. For "variance" I got an exception and for "distinct count" I got 2 after the first group and 4 after the second!