# Some group calculations over the values returned by a subreport doesn't work

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a simple pair of report and subreport.
My records are grouped, and at the end of each group I want to summarize the data of that group. Pretty straightforward, except that the data I want to summarize is generated by a subreport in each record.

I created some variables to store the values returned by the subreport.

```
<variable name="returnSum" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Group" resetGroup="group" calculation="System">
    <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></initialValueExpression>
</variable>
<variable name="returnAvg" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Group" resetGroup="group" calculation="System">
    <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></initialValueExpression>
</variable>
<variable name="returnLowest" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Group" resetGroup="group" calculation="System">
    <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></initialValueExpression>
</variable>
<variable name="returnStdDeviation" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Group" resetGroup="group" calculation="System">
    <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></initialValueExpression>
</variable>
```

Those same variables are also supposed to receive the calculation for the group. Because of this (thanks to [dada67](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39343573/2761418)):

```
<subreport>
    <returnValue subreportVariable="return" toVariable="returnSum" calculation="Sum"/>
    <returnValue subreportVariable="return" toVariable="returnAvg" calculation="Average"/>
    <returnValue subreportVariable="return" toVariable="returnLowest" calculation="Lowest"/>
    <returnValue subreportVariable="return" toVariable="returnStdDeviation" calculation="StandardDeviation"/>
</subreport>
```

In fact this almost work. This is what I get:
[image]

So my question is: why does the group calculations over elements returned by a subreport work for **sum** and **lowest** operations, but not for **average** and **standard deviation**?

Here is the full source code for the [report](http://pastebin.com/7yQm8A4B) and [subreport](http://pastebin.com/khKAARTL).

**UPDATE**

I'm quite sure it has to do with the use of groups. I simply removed the group and put the "group summary" in the report summary and it worked.

[image]

Comment: I have test your jrxml and can confirm the behavior (I can't see nothing wrong in it), to me it seems like a bug

Comment: While average is easy to solve (divide sum with count), Variance and StdDev will be tough, since it needs the mean calculated, I guess your only work around is a Scriplet

Comment: @PetterFriberg is right, it's a bug.  The latest development code has a fix, average and standard deviation should work fine.

Comment: @dada67 consider to pass an answer, with version in which it is solved.

Comment: The fix will probably be included in the next release (6.3.1).  For now you can only get the fix by building the latest source code.